# Merging after splitting dataframe in groups (with a loop)

Tags: python

I have a lot of value (returns) for a lot of companies. I am doing an Event Study and I need to do a regression for each Companies (group_ID).

[image: DF]

So I did this:
[image: Code]

So the problem is: my df a_bn contains an a value for each unique group_id so the lenght is 1867 rows. I would like to join the a value in another df thats contains all the other information about the companie (group_id) but the lenght is 1397187 rows. I want to join the value of a for each group_ID. So for each rows, when it's the same group_ID, I have the same a value. So I can have 1397187 rows who are matching the groups that I did for the loop. Thank you!

I tried simply merging but its not working because the values of a are not matching the groups and only creating NaN value for the rest of the df.

Answer (score 0):

Your regression outcome `a`, `B`, and `R2` are saved in a list. It would be best if you created a DataFrame that contains the group id. This DataFrame can be used to perform the merge, e.g.

```
df_params = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'B': B, 'R2': R2, 'group_id': groups})
```

The parameters can then be joined be the merge method:

```
df_bn.merge(df_params, on="group_id", how="left")
```

But as `df_bn` is a time series DataFrame, the parameters will be replicated in each group by the number of time stamps.